# Unitegallery not working with repeat control

Tags: xpages, repeat

I would like to use Unitegallery carrousel with some pictures who's urls are in a view. I tried the following :

```
<xp:this.resources>  
<xp:script src="/JQueryXSnippet.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>

<script type='text/javascript' src='unitegallery/js/unitegallery.min.js'></script>  
<link rel='stylesheet' href='unitegallery/css/unite-gallery.css' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='unitegallery/themes/carousel/ug-theme-carousel.js'></script>

<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view4" databaseName="pictures.nsf"
        viewName="pictures3" keys="demo">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
$(document).ready(
function() {
x$("#{id:gallery}").unitegallery({
gallery_theme: "carousel",
tile_width: 60,                     //tile width
tile_height: 60,                    //tile height

});
}
);
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:panel>
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
<xp:repeat id="repeat6" rows="30" var="pictureData" value="#{view4}">
                    <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField11">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var thisPicture= pictureData.getColumnValue("bigPicture");
dezeAfbeeldingen ="<img src='"+thisPicture+"'data-image='"+thisPicture+"'style='height: 60px;width: 60px;'></img>";
return dezeAfbeeldingen;}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
  </div>
  </xp:panel>
```

The result : nothing is displayed.
In Google chrome console I get an error : "Uncaught Error: The item should not be image type " and at the right side         unitegallery.min.js:4"

The repeat is run , the pictures are found , but don't display and give this error.

When I replace the repeat with "hardcoded " image references everything seems to work....

**EDIT**

thisPicture is in fact the complete url of the picture so for example : 
server/product/picture.nsf/O/unid/$File/picturename.jpg

HTML output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css/2Eabootstrap/xsptheme/xsp.css&amp;2Eabootstrap/bootstrap311/css/bootstrap.min.css&amp;@Da&amp;2Eabootstrap/xpages300.css.css">
<script type="text/javascript">var dojoConfig = {locale: 'nl-nl'};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.9.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.nl-nl/@Iq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspClientDojo")</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/bootstrap/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/bootstrap/bootstrap311/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/bootstrap/xpages300.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/web.nsf/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/web.nsf/JQueryXSnippet"></script>
</head>
<body class="xsp tundra">
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/web/web.nsf/test_unite_gallery2.xsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<script src="unitegallery/js/unitegallery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="unitegallery/css/unite-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script src="unitegallery/themes/carousel/ug-theme-carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function() {
x$("gallery").unitegallery({
gallery_theme: "carousel",
tile_width: 60,                     //tile width
tile_height: 60,                    //tile height

});
}
);
</script>
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;"><div id="view:_id1:repeat6">
<span id="view:_id1:repeat6:0:computedField11"><img src='server/product/picture.nsf/O/unid/$File/picturename1.jpg'data-image='server/product/picture.nsf/O/unid/$File/picturename1.jpg'style='height: 60px;width: 60px;'></img>
</span>
<span id="view:_id1:repeat6:1:computedField11"><img src='server/product/picture.nsf/O/unid/$File/picturename2.jpg'data-image='server/product/picture.nsf/O/unid/$File/picturename2.jpg'style='height: 60px;width: 60px;'></img>
</span>
```

etc for other pictures

```
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="$$viewid" id="view:_id1__VUID" value="!e4h2ba0vbj!">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspexecid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitvalue">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitscroll">
<input type="hidden" name="view:_id1" value="view:_id1"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2**

More details about the error I get in chrome console :
"Uncaught Error: The item should not be image type " and at the right side         unitegallery.min.js:4"

when I click on the arrow I get more details :

```
fillItemsArray @ unitegallery.min.js:4
runGallery @ unitegallery.min.js:4
UniteGalleryMain.run @ unitegallery.min.js:4
jQuery.fn.unitegallery @ unitegallery.min.js:9
(anonymous function) @ test_unite_gallery2.xsp:23
n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
```

Under resources there's a red 1 behind unitegallery.min.js , and gives the same error message for it (The item should not be image type).

**EDIT3**

When I have a look at the difference of the html generated by the repeat or the hard coded picture references I see that there's a double " (good) and a ' (bad) for the img and src tags. How can I change that ?

Comment: What does pictureData.getColumnValue("bigPicture") contain? Please add this and an example of the HTML output from the repeat.

Comment: Does it work if you add a space before "data-Image" and "style"?

Comment: I would have a look at two things.  The use of single quotes and the spacing as Knut Herrmann says.

Comment: if 'server' is the server name then add http:// in front of the url - else it will try and load the resource from the 'server' directory. Have a look at your browser's developer tools and you will most like see requests with error 404

Comment: Per , server is indeed the servername , but already includes the http://
I don't see any error 404 I'll put a second edit above with more details of the error I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
$(document).ready(
function() {
$("#gallery").unitegallery({
gallery_theme: "carousel",
tile_width: 60,                     //tile width
tile_height: 60,                    //tile height

});
}
);
]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:panel>
        <div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
            <xp:repeat rows="100" var="pictureData"  value="#{view4}" removeRepeat="true">
                <xp:image url="#{javascript:pictureData.getColumnValue("bigPicture")}">
                    <xp:this.attrs>
                        <xp:attr name="data-image" 
                            value="#{javascript:pictureData.getColumnValue("bigPicture")}">
                        </xp:attr>
                    </xp:this.attrs>
                </xp:image>
            </xp:repeat>
        </div>
    </xp:panel>
```

You get the error "The item should not be image type" because unitegallery doesn't like the `<div>`s and `<span>`s within `<div id="gallery"> ... </div>`. There have to be only `<img>`s.

As you showed in your question your rendered html looks like this

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
    <div id="view:_id1:repeat6">
        <span id="view:_id1:repeat6:0:computedField11">
            <img src='server/product/.../picturename1.jpg' 
                 data-image='server/product/.../picturename1.jpg'>
            </img>
        </span>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You get rid of repeat-div with repeat's attribute `removeRepeat="true"`.

You can avoid computed field's span with `<xp:image ... />`. Set the additional attribute "data-image" as an additional attribute.

Unitegallery doesn't like ids with ":" in it like they get rendered by XPages. That's why embed html `<div id="gallery"` to define the place for Unitegallery carrousel. As it's already client side html you can address it direct in your client side code with `$("#gallery").`

The code above renders the gallery-div with nested repeat to just

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
     <img src='server/product/.../picturename1.jpg' 
          data-image='server/product/.../picturename1.jpg'>
     </img>
     ...
</div>
```

and this works well for Unitegallery.

Comment: Knut, 
Thanks a lot. Not only for the sollution , but also for the expanation. I learned a lot this way !

Comment: Marc, I am happy I could help you and I learned about Unitegallery this way - it's a nice tool.

Comment: I have the same issue, but the parents div's are created by unitegallery plugin. http://ctrlv.in/618401